# MySQL group by wildcard (*) in expected output

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, wildcard

Recently I did a coding assessment and came across this database query problem which I was unable to solve. After the assessment, I attempted to research for similar problems online but was unable to find any. (Maybe I'm using the wrong search keywords)

I can't refer back to the exact assessment question, but here is a simplified version.

**Given table:**

```
|email            |sent|
|-----------------|----|
|abc@email.com    |6   |
|xyxxz@email.com  |10  |
|hbd@zmail.com    |2   |
|yaaap@hemail.com |5   |
|...              |... |
|sfhas@heymail.com|7   |
```

**Expected output:**

```
|email        |sum(sent)|
|-------------|---------|
|*@email.com  |16       |
|*@zmail.com  |28       |
|*@hemail.com |92       |
|...          |...      |
|*@heymail.com|48       |
```

How should I achieve this ? I know there are keywords such as **LIKE** and **REGEXP** which allows you to filter words based on regular expressions. But how should I **GROUP BY** with the wildcard **(*)** included in the output ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTR` to get the right part of the email address :

```
SELECT CONCAT('*', SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@'))) as email, SUM(sent)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)` would also do a similar job